# django admin renders links on readonly foreign key to which I don't have permission

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using the latest django version (3.2.8) and I have the following problem:

1. My user can see model "inspection" via permisson "view_inspection"
2. My user cannot (!) see any foreign keys due to missing permissions
3. The readonly-foreign key is still rendered as a link which leads to a 403 page

What I need:

- Showing just the name of the object and not linking to it.

[image]

Any ideas how I can fix this? Looks like a bug somehow... Googleing and browsing stack overflow didn't return any solutions.

Thx in advance!

Comment: Can you share the ModelAdmin that produces this result?

Comment: I can but I just went through the django code and there is no handling for this case... :(

Comment: Interesting, seems this was introduced in 3.2 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#django-contrib-admin

Comment: And I have to fix it now  After looking at the code I have absolutely no idea how to do this...

Comment: You can override the template and a) not render links (like before); b) check permissions on each related object before rendering link. The latter will add as many db queries to your request as many related objects there are

Comment: Unfortunately not that easy because the link and the data are entangled within a property of the field. I created a bug ticket at their bugtracker: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/33171#ticket

Comment: Such a shame how this ticket is still won't fix and I'm having the same issue nearly 1 year later. This is not really clean.